# Change login for report deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, bids

I'm trying to deploy a report to one of my servers but I get an error stating ***The permissions granted to user 'User A' are insufficient for performing this operation***.  However, I am logged into the machine as User B who *does* have access to deploy the report.

How can I force BIDS to prompt me again for login so that I can login as User B instead of User A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by going to "Control Panel -> Credential Manager" and then deleting the Windows Credentials associated with the report server (ex. "reportsr2.blah.com") that were referring to User A.  Then I closed and re-opened the report and it correctly used my User B credentials and I was able to deploy the report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is not able to find the right account in Credentials Manager, is possible to add the correct credentials in Credentials Manager by clicking on 'add a windows credential' option;

Note: in the Internet or network address field type just the base address of the URL.